# Recursive tree search using postgresql join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree

I have a table `stories` and a table `blockings` which has the columns `story_id` (referencing a story), and a `blocked_story_id` (also referencing a story, which is blocked by the `story_id`)

I'm trying to construct a query to return all the stories in order of precedence based on their blockers - so blockers first, traversing down the tree.

One story can be blocked by many stories, and can itself be a blocker for many stories.

I've been reading and re-reading the PostgreSQL docs on `WITH RECURSIVE` but I'm a little lost on where I should be going with this, and how to construct the relevant query.

I have got as far as:

```
select s.id, b.story_id as blocker_id
from stories s
left outer join blockings b on s.id = b.blocked_story_id
where s.deleted_at is null
```

as for getting a list of stories and their blockers, but some pointers as to what I need to join/union to get the desired result would be helpful.

### Context

I want to know which stories I can work on first. So I want an output that contains all stories in an order that allows me to work top down and never hit a blocked story.

The content of the `blockings` table gives me a simple join table between stories that block one another. The `story_id` being the blocker, the `blocked_story_id` being the one being blocked.

### Sample Data

#### Stories

```
id | title
------------------
1  | Story title 1
2  | Story title 2
3  | Story title 3
4  | Story title 4
5  | Story title 5
```

### Blockings

```
story_id | blocked_story_id
---------------------------
4        | 2
4        | 3
3        | 1
3        | 5
```

I would expect to see the following result:

```
id | title
------------------
4  | Story title 4
2  | Story title 2
3  | Story title 3
1  | Story title 1
5  | Story title 5
```

Comment: Hi, please add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @S-Man added sample data and expected output

Comment: Please explain it a little bit. As I can see your expected output equals the table content of stories (in a different order). it is not quiet clear to me what the content of blockings means.

Comment: @S-Man I've added some context to why I want this. Is that helpful or have I muddled things more?

Comment: Ok and where do you want the recursion? it is not clear to me, how you came to the order 4,2,3,1,5. Why do you start with 4? Why is 2 the next one?

Comment: Notice that a table cannot be ordered by the order of inserting if you do not have any additional information. `SELECT * FROM blockings` never ensures the order you gave. Is it a numeric order?

Comment: @S-Man I was using my (limited) understanding of breadth-first recursion to determine that given the dependency tree with 4 at the top, then 2 and 3 under it, and 1 and 5 under 3, I would expect to see a top down, left to right order.

Comment: Essentially, Once I've done story 4, I want to move on to the next unblocked stories, which would be 2 and 3, and if I then unblocked 1 and 5 by completing 3, the order becomes irrelevant, but precedence should be given to unblocked stories

Comment: This is not as easy as it sounds. Main problem: without an specific order you cannot ensure a certain order. So how should the query know the starting point? What is your first column? You HAVE to give an order criterion. Otherwise your result becomes completely random especially on greater data sets

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: Because it is not clear to me why you need a recursion for finding the blocked stories (Which can be achieved easily by `SELECT blocked_story_id FROM blocking`) I would ask you for further information. A real recursion case could be: "*All blocking that are reachable from story 4*" or something like that.

---

Here's what I've done so far as I understood your problem:

Your `blocking` table says: story 4 blocks stories 2 and 3. Story 3 blocks stories 1 and 5. So there are blocked stories 1, 2, 3, 5. Because of the recursion, story 4 can block 1 and 5 via 3. So there a two ways of blocking them (directly with starting point 3 and and from starting point 4 via 3). I gave out all possible paths with this query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE blocks AS (
    SELECT blocked_story_id, ARRAY[story_id]::int[] as path FROM blockings

    UNION

    SELECT bk.blocked_story_id, b.path || bk.story_id
    FROM blockings bk INNER JOIN blocks b ON b.blocked_story_id = bk.story_id
)
SELECT b.blocked_story_id, s.title, b.path 
FROM blocks b INNER JOIN stories s ON s.id = b.blocked_story_id;
```

Result:

```
blocked_story_id   title     path
2                  Title 2   {4}
3                  Title 3   {4}
1                  Title 1   {3}
5                  Title 5   {3}
1                  Title 1   {4,3}
5                  Title 5   {4,3}
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1a870997ef948fb72b96d0b62c0ea9a5)

Answer (score 0):

@S-Man I figured it out thanks to your help pointing me in the right direction.

```sql
WITH recursive blockings_tree(id, title, path) AS (
SELECT stories.id, title, ARRAY[blockings.blocked_story_id, blockings.story_id]
    FROM stories
    LEFT OUTER JOIN blockings ON blockings.story_id = stories.id
UNION ALL
SELECT stories.id, stories.title, path || stories.id
    FROM blockings_tree
    JOIN blockings ON blockings.story_id = blockings_tree.id
    JOIN stories ON blockings.blocked_story_id = stories.id
    WHERE NOT blockings.blocked_story_id = any(path)
)
SELECT stories.* 
FROM stories 
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(path) AS path FROM blockings_tree GROUP BY id) bt ON bt.id = stories.id
ORDER BY path
```